# How do you display information from another class using @Html.DisplayFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am experiencing a problem where the `view` is not allowing me to display the full amount of information.

**WorseningParameter Class**

```
public class MatrixWorseningParameter
{   
    [Key]
    public int worseningParameterID { get; set; }
    public int paramID { get; set; }
    public int paramID2 { get; set; }

    public virtual MatrixParameter MatrixParameters { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MatrixWorseningPrinciple> MatrixWorseningPrinciples { get; set; }
}
```

**Parameter Class**

```
public class MatrixWorseningParameter
{
    [Key]
    public int worseningParameterID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Main Parameter")]
    public int paramID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Worsening Parameter")]
    public int paramID2 { get; set; }

    public virtual MatrixParameter MatrixParameters { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MatrixWorseningPrinciple> MatrixWorseningPrinciples { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
    @model Main.Models.Matrix.MatrixParameter
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.MatrixWorseningParameters)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.paramID2)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MatrixParameters.fullParam)
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Add", "../MatrixWorseningParameters/Create", new { id = Model.paramID })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        MatrixWorseningParameter matrixWorseningParameter = db.WorseningParameters.Find(id);
        if (matrixWorseningParameter == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(matrixWorseningParameter);
    }
```

The result I get on the view is it displays the correct `paramID2` number, but sadly the text to refer to the `paramID` is incorrect.  It is displaying the text for the `paramID`.

What should I do to overcome this?

Comment: Do you have `@model Product` syntax at the top of your view code? If so, are you sure this syntax works: `@foreach (var item in model.Condition)`? Shouldn't it be `@foreach (var item in Model.Conditions)` instead?

Comment: I'm confused. Your **Model** is a **single Product object**; you want to display value of **name**. **Condition** class doesn't have **name** property. If you want to display **name** from Product, you don't even need to **foreach** loop.

Comment: @ekad I noticed the syntax with Condition earlier and updated my code to reflect the plural.

Comment: I guess the easiest way of dealing with this is to add a product name to the `Condition` class. I was hoping to be able to use the `productID` from `Condition` to call the appropriate information from the `Product` class.

Comment: @Win the code I am actually working on is more complex that the code above.  This is simply a direct representation of that code. Solve the above and I will have the answer I need to solve my actual code.

Comment: Have now posted with actual code, rather than using a representation of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can add another `DisplayFor` saying below and which should work perfect since you said your `condition` class is a child of `product` and thus will contain all the properties defined in `product` class (`Title`, `Description`, `Date`)

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Title)
```

Comment: Actually, I have just worked out the Condition is not a child class to Product. That's why your answer, and exactly what I tried before, didn't work. Any ideas how to do it, if they are not parent and child?

Comment: @TJSUK, Then you will have to define those properties in condition class (or) Inherit from Product (or) have an instance of Product in your condition class as member variable.

Comment: I thought I had, within the `Condition` class I have a virtual connection - public virtual Product Products and in the `Products` I have the respective ICollections<>

Comment: @TJSUK, don't say that in comment rather post the relevant code in your post.

Comment: I have updated the question. Probably makes more sense now.

Comment: @TJSUK, Yes saw your post and yes it can't be done cause you are looping through `ICollection<Condition> Conditions` which certainly don't have `Name` property. If you want to get the product name then get it outside the loop saying `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name)`